# How to use a local variable as part of a MySQL query (Qt C++)

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

As the question says im trying to query a `MySQL` database using a local variable for the where clause. I know in java you could use the `+` operator to just insert local variables within the query string which obviously isn't the same in `C++`. so i thought maybe id use a string stream:

```
void test::something(double car_id)
{
 std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carID = '";
    ss << car_id << "'";
    QString query_string = QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
    QSqlQuery query(query_string);
    // execute the query
    query.exec();
    std::cout << query.value("carID").toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

but this also isn't working, any help would be great because I can't seem to find the answer

cheers

Comment: How it doesn't work? What's the problem?

Comment: Never ever construct SQL queries with string concatenation. Injection is very likely to be possible. Use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)!

Comment: it says that `QSQLQuery::value is not positioned on a valid record`

Comment: After `exec` you have to do `next` first. See the documentation of `next`

Comment: That wasn't my edit. I only approved and improved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of appending the variable to the query string you should parameterized queries instead. So, something like this:

```
void test::something(double car_id){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carID = ?");
    query.addBindValue(car_id);
    query.exec();
    std::cout << query.value("carID").toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

Or with named binds:

```
void test::something(double car_id){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carID = :car_id");
    query.bindValue(":car_id", car_id);
    query.exec();
    std::cout << query.value("carID").toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is very true. But AFAIK it doesn't solve the problem. Insert `query.next()`

Comment: was just about to say the same cheers @leemes and thanks WOLPH this looks good, see my question was also asking how to use local variables in SQL statements properly which you have answered ill accept

Comment: @WoLpH how would i use this bind value with more than one parameter? thanks again

Comment: [See here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values) - For multiple parameters, you may want to use named placeholders.

Comment: @AngryDuck: simply add multiple `addBindValue` calls and more question marks.

Comment: and then just list the addbind values in the same order as the question marks right?

Comment: Bingo, that's exactly it :) Alternatively you can also use `bindValue` to bind by name which is slightly more readable. I'll add an example of that as well.

Comment: would it be possible to do `SELECT * FROM :table1 WHERE :field1 = :what` and then just define them as eg. `query.bindValue(":table1", "car");` or would that not work?

Comment: No, that won't work. The `bindValue` methods are only for values to filter on. For tables and columns you'll have to do string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

if carID is numeric column in DB you dont need quotes

```
QString query_string = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carID = " 
+ QString::number(car_id);
```

otherwise

```
QString query_string = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carID = '" 
+ QString::number(car_id) + "'";
```

Note 1: you shouldn't use this approach at all, but look at bind query parameters. For a lot of different reasons (injections, escaping, types formatting/conversion etc)

Note 2: why on earth people like to mix STL basic types with QT basic types (strings, basic containers etc). Never saw any advantages of this, except completely unreadable code and conversion issues.